# C# How read a string to listView?

Tags: c#, string, listview, load

How to load string from a txt file to the listView?
I have a txt file with three lines of characters.
I read the first line of a txt file into the first row in listView and etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if your line contains everything you need and doesn't need to be split after you can use ListBox instead of ListView

```
foreach(string line in File.ReadAllLines(pathToYourFile))
    ListBox.Items.Add(line);
```

Or if you really need ListView you can use

```
foreach(string line in File.ReadAllLines(pathToYourFile))
    listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(line));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use iostreamreader .. then use readline function .. then fill the listview

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"yourtextfile");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Linq example for you.

```
using System.Linq;

...    

System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(line => listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(line)));
```

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
using System.IO; <-- to read the file
```

Then, if you can use a listbox, addrange works well without the loop:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
string[] s_array = File.ReadAllLines( -- your file path -- );
listBox1.Items.AddRange(s_array);
```

If you're using a list view, then the loop suggested by Blablablaster above works well